# Image not showing once uploaded to live server

Tags: html, asp.net, css, image, upload

I am getting the Captcha image from another aspx page where i coded to create random images and i referenced that aspx page in image source but it works fine on local host but i am unable to see the captcha image when i uploaded it to live server.
 Here is code to reference aspx page

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src="CImage.aspx" />
```

you can see its not showing on [live website](http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/pour-nous-joindre).
I have tried with many ways to get the image aspx page and even i tried with firebug to detect error in path getting but failed to get this.
Please provide me hint that where is the error or if i am missing any other things to show image on live.

Comment: Because there is no image by the name http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/CImage.aspx it gives a `404 not found` error

Comment: Its because of url rewriting.

Comment: @SajithNair but its getting image from CImage.aspx on local server so what i need to do ?

Comment: @user3560009 check the redirection rule on production server

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari if i need to ask from customer support for redirection rules? i am using arvixe webhosting for my website

Comment: @user3560009 First make sure that the page is uploaded on server and it returns valid image

Comment: so u fixed it, it is working now?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i have fixed it without doing url rewriting or any of above methods that others told me in comments.
I simply add all code to generate random images behind aspx page and then add <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CaptchaImage.aspx"/>